# Issue with corrupted assets flutter, fastapi, Lambda, ApiGateway, S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm running into a strange issue with the following setup:

Flutter app that uploads an image to a fastapi backend thats served from a lambda function through ApiGateway, which uses bota3 to upload and serve the image from s3.

My python routes look like this.

```
@router.get("{filePath:path}")
async def read_root(filePath, current_user: CognitoClaims = Depends(get_current_user)):
    user: User = await get_user(current_user.username)
    company: Company = await get_company(user);

    try:
        response = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={
            'Bucket': settings.s3_bucket,
            'Key': filePath.strip("/")
        }, ExpiresIn=3600)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None
    return response

@router.post("")
async def add_file(current_user: CognitoClaims = Depends(get_current_user), file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    user: User = await get_user(current_user.username)
    company: Company = await get_company(user);

    file_name = file.filename;

    full_name = f"{current_user.username}/uploads/{file_name}"

    try:
        s3.upload_fileobj(file.file, settings.s3_bucket, full_name)
    
        response = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={
                'Bucket': settings.s3_bucket,
                'Key': full_name
            }, ExpiresIn=3600);
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None
        
    return {
        "path": full_name,
        'url': response
    };
```

The endpoints and functions are all successful, but the images uploaded to s3 seem to be corrupted.

The strange part is that I am able to use these endpoints perfectly when hitting using postman, and even stranger than that it runs fine locally from the flutter app. so i can only assume its an issue related to my ApiGateway setup.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to REST API Gateways defaulting to handling all payloads as text. In order for a payload to be handled as binary, the media type for the payload  must be added to the `binaryMediaTypes` for the REST API Gateway.

In the specific case of file uploads via `UploadFile` in FastAPI, the media type is `multipart/form-data`, and so this needs to be added to the `binaryMediaTypes` configuration for the gateway. In my case I'm deploying via CDK and so on my `lambdaRestApi` I needed to set `binaryMediaTypes` to `["multipart/form-data"]`.

More information can be found in the AWS [Working with binary media types for REST APIs Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html).

Comment: HI Oliver thanks for the answer, 

This was actually something that i worked on a while back and managed to find a way around, i think by using pre-signed urls. So not really able to test your answer without going back and undoing everything lol, but your answer makes sense :)